# Define subprojects in another file than build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to define a [multi-project build](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html) with a *consequent* number of subprojects:

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── project/
│   ├── dependencies.scala
│   ├── tasks.scala
│   └── settings.scala
├── lib_1/
│   └── src/
├── ...
└── lib_n/
    └── src/
```

Those subprojects are currently defined in `build.sbt`:

```scala
val outputJarFolder = "/some/path/"
lazy val comonSettings = /* ... */

lazy val lib_1 = (project in file ("lib1")).settings(
    name:="LibOne",
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(scalaTest, jsonLib, scalaXML, commonsIo),
    Compile/packageBin/artifactPath := file(outputJarFolder + "lib1.jar")
)

// ... more libs ...

lazy val lib_n = (project in file ("libn")).settings(
    name:="LibLast",
    commonSettings,
    Compile/packageBin/artifactPath := file(outputJarFolder + "libn.jar")
)
    .depensOn(lib_2, lib_12)
```

**How can I define those subprojects in another file than build.sbt** in order to "unclog" that file? I want to still be able to define them in their lexicographic order (so `lazy` is a must). I'm working with sbt version 1.2.8 and scala 2.10.

---

I've tried:

1. Putting the declaration of those `lib_k` variables in a scala file and importing it --> sbt says: *"classes cannot be lazy"*.
2. Putting those declaration in an object (or in a class and instantiate it in `build.sbt`) --> `sbt projects` doesn't list any subproject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Directories.html#sbt+build+definition+files) mentions it, but doesn't emphasize too much (perhaps to avoid encouragement for too much variation in how builds are defined in the absence of a common convention):

> The build definition is described in `build.sbt` (**actually any files named `*.sbt`**) in the project’s base directory.

So you can split your `build.sbt` file into several separate `.sbt` files in the root of the project with different names.

I also recommend reading documentation on [Organizing the build](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Organizing-Build.html).

Comment: https://kubuszok.com/2018/relearn-your-sbt/ is also a good read ;)